# calculating an equation given a certain input from a user with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, user-input

JavaScript newbie here.
I am tasked with calculating a user's monthly payment by using a given equation. I am having trouble with getting the values from the user.

```
const loanAmount = document.getElementById('loan-amount');
const loanYears = document.getElementById('loan-years');
const loanRate = document.getElementById('loan-Rate');
const span = document.querySelector('span');
const form = document.getElementById("calc-form");


form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
console.log('hello')

    makeLogo();
  
  });



  function makeLogo(loanAmount, loanYears, loanRate) {
    const principle = loanAmount.value 
    const n = loanYears.value * 12;
    const i = loanRate.value / 12;


const monthylPayment = (principle* i)/1-(1+ i)** -(n);

span.innerText = monthylPayment;
  }
```

This is what I have so far and am getting an error for the variables in the makeLogo function.

Comment: I would suggest that you first resolve the values of the inputs, then use those values as parameters into makeLogo() then return the value and assign to your span.innerText this is different from currently having your function deal with the elements themselves. it should make debugging easier.

Comment: The script is at the bottom of the body

Comment: Error message = appTwo.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at makeLogo (appTwo.js:19:34)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (appTwo.js:12:5)
makeLogo @ appTwo.js:19
(anonymous) @ appTwo.js:12

Comment: `function makeLogo(loanAmount, loanYears, loanRate)` This means the function expects 3 parameters and since you don't pass any when you call `makeLogo();`, they are all undefined. To have the function use the global variables, remove the params: `function makeLogo()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to separate your inputs, calculations and rendering into separate functions. try to keep functions as simple as possible.
You will need to re-evaluate your monthly cost calculator, but here is a working example which takes input, calculates and then renders into form fields.

```js
document.getElementById("calc-form").addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var loanAmount = document.getElementById('loan-amount').value;
    console.log(loanAmount);
    var loanYears = document.getElementById('loan-years').value;
    var loanRate = document.getElementById('loan-rate').value;
    
    var monthlyPayment = makeLogo( loanAmount, loanYears, loanRate );    
    console.log(monthlyPayment);
    // the monthly has now been calculated, simply put it where you'd like
    var calculated = document.getElementById('calculated');    
    calculated.value = monthlyPayment;
    
    var totalRepayment = document.getElementById('totalRepayment');    
    totalRepayment.value = monthlyPayment * ( loanYears * 12 );
    
} );
  
function makeLogo( principle, loanYears, loanRate) {
  var n = loanYears * 12;
  var i = loanRate / 12;
  var result = ( principle * i) / 1 - ( 1 + i )**-( n );
  return result;
}
```

```html
<html>
<form action='submit' id ='calc-form'>
Loan Amount:<input id ='loan-amount'></input><BR/>
Loan Years:<input id='loan-years'></input><BR/>
Loan Rate:<input id='loan-rate'></input><BR/>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
<span id='span-output'>
Monthly Payment :<input id='calculated' readonly><BR/>
Total Re-Payment :<input id='totalRepayment' readonly>
</span>
</html>
```